# How can I remove Category And Search bar in Evernote?

Tags: evernote

I use latest version Evernote 6.16.4.8094, the Category And Search bar occupy many screen space of my laptop with Windows 10, you know my laptop is only 12 inch.

You can see the following Image.

How can I remove Category And Search bar in Evernote?

**Image**

[image]